# How to return constants field

Tags: java

I have a CSV file with a list of state  (All types are in String) that is needed to be uploaded in the webservice. Every state has a country field (Country type).

The country class content is something like this

[image]

**Note: The Country class is not mine so I cannot change it**.

I can access the "United State" value using `Country.US`. Is it possible to access it the other way around? `"United States"` then my return value would be `Country.US`? I need it to be in the Country type so I can pass it on the webservice.

[image]

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: You could use reflection for `field.get().equals("United States")` -> `field.getName()` but I doubt you would.

Comment: think of using the properties file and property class for your scenario.

Comment: "if the SETTER method requires Country class as parameter?" what do you mean by this?

Comment: @Smutje looks like OP may try to use reflection to get the name of the field which has `"United States"` as value.

Comment: This looks like [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/182862). Please explain your real problem so you can get accurate help.

Comment: Have you considered using an `Enum` instead?

Comment: The Country should be an `enum` added in Java ten years ago.  If you did that, you would have type safety and you would see conde completetion. i.e. it would suggest a list of countries as you type.

Comment: You need to pass in an instance of `Country`; `Country.US` would not work here since it is a `String`. There seems to be more in the `Country` class that you did not show.

Comment: The code was hidden from us! I don't know how I can access it

Comment: the Country class doesn't belong to her so cant use an Enum here

Comment: Note: Country.US is a String, but your method expects a `Country` not a String.

Comment: Aside from the String, there's a Country inside the Country class

Comment: Please post all the necessary info to understand the problem. Don't post part by part, otherwise you won't receive the help you want/need.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have an access on the Country class itself. That's why I don't know how they implement it

Comment: you can do is get all the fields of the country class using reflection then add the fields to a map and while setting the country for state iterate the map and set the value

Comment: *Sorry but I don't have an access on the Country class itself*. Ok then, try using a decompiler like [jd](http://jd.benow.ca/) :). You won't be able to modify the code but you may get a better idea on what you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you expect that would ever work, magically?
What if you have 2 classes, each containing a static field that resolves to "United States". Which should the JVM magically choose to give you when it sees that String somewhere? Or should it just give one at random?

You can of course have some kind of custom resolver that does it. Something along the lines of:

```
public Country countryFromString(final String s) {
  switch s:
    case "United States": return Country.US;
    default: return null;
}
```

Comment: Note that `Country.US` is a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can get Variables :

```
Field[] fields = Country.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(fields[i]);
}
```

Output that returns `Country.US`:

```
public static final java.lang.String com.package.test.Country.US
```

Comment: This seems really overkill for the problem and doesn't solve it. Note that `Country.US` is a `String` and OP needs an instance of `Country`.

Answer (score 0):

If all the Constant class has static final String countries you could use reflection. But still like people say I dont get the point in all this.

```
    for (Field field : Country.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if((String)field.get(Country.class).equals("United state")){
            return field.getName();
        }
    }
    //Throw exception
```